# Change CountDownTimer class default animation

Tags: android, animation, countdowntimer

So I have been searching all over Internet past weeks and unfortunately I cant find the solution.

**A simple question:** How to change `CountDownTimer` class default animation? i mean the animation on changing text on every `tick`. Currently after every tick text change with no animation at all.

Is there any good way to change animation to Up to down when changing every tick on `CountDownTimer` class? Here is the code in case someone confuse what i am talking about:

```
public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer 
{
        public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
        {

            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
        {
            millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            System.out.println(hms);

            CountText.setText(hms);
        }
}
```

maybe adding up to down animation on `ontick`? 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: giving down vote without telling anything in comment section is not a good idea. its new question and there are people out there who have same problem. your downvote not going to help them. Please explaine down votes. Thanks

Comment: I dont know about up to down animation but i can show you down to up animation on textview.

Comment: with CountdownTimer class? becourse i want those animation on every second of ticks in textview . Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: yes with CoutdownTimer class.

Comment: please write codes in answer section. This will surely helpfull Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [HTextView](https://github.com/hanks-zyh/HTextView) library we can achieve nice down to up animation.

First add dependency to your project

```
compile 'hanks.xyz:htextview-library:0.1.5'
```

Add this layout as per your requirement.

```
<com.hanks.htextview.HTextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Add this to your java file.

```
HTextView hTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.temp);

        hTextView = (HTextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        hTextView.setAnimateType(HTextViewType.EVAPORATE);
}
```

And last set this line to `onTick` of `CounterClass`.

```
hTextView.animateText(hms);
```

Comment: Thanks it is working! There is any library i can use to make up-down animation?

Comment: I dont know about it but you can check [CountDownAnimation](https://github.com/IvanRF/CountDownAnimation) and [Android-FlipDigitView](https://github.com/Vinayrraj/Android-FlipDigitView).

Comment: Thanks it were really helpful :)